# How usage of member initializer list prevents creation of redundant object in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, object-construction

I have a question regarding difference in initializing an object with and without constructor member initializer list.

In the following code snippet there are two classes `Test1` and `Test2` each with two constructors, objects of these two classes are created in the default constructor of another class `Example`.
Object of `Test1` is created with one parameter in member initializer list, whereas that of `Test2` is created with one parameter inside constructor body of `Example`.

```
class Test1 {
public:
    Test1()      { cout << "Test1 is created with no argument"; }
    Test1(int a) { cout << "Test1 is created with 1 argument"; }
};

class Test2 {
public:
    Test2()      { cout << "Test2 is created with no argument"; }
    Test2(int a) { cout << "Test2 is created with 1 argument"; }
};

class Example {
public:
    Test1 objTest1;
    Test2 objTest2;

    Example() : objTest1(Test1(50)) 
    {
            objTest2 = Test2(50);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Example e;
}
```

The output of the above code is :

`Test1 is created with 1 argument`

`Test2 is created with no argument`

`Test2 is created with 1 argument`

**My Questions**

- Why does object of `Test2` is created twice? (The one which is created without member initializer.)
- What had happened to the redundant object of `Test2`? Does it still occupies some memory?
- How does member initializer list works in initializing class member variables?
- Is there is any performance benefit in using member initializer list? (As Test1 is created only once)

Comment: `Test2` is first create without argument (default constructor), and then a second time when you call it's constructor inside the `Example` constructor body. What's unclear about that behavior?

Comment: When you create Example e it creates objTest2 and then you overwrite it with a new object, while you specify how to initialize objTest2 in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Example` constructor is (implicitly) equivalent to

```
Example() : objTest1(Test1(50)), objTest2()
{
        objTest2 = Test2(50);
}
```

That is, the `objTest2` object is constructed and initialized once implicitly (this is inserted by the compiler).

Then you inside the body explicitly construct and initialize a temporary `Test2` object that is used to ***assign*** to `objTest2`.

---

Also note that in the initializer list `objTest1(Test1(50))` constructs a temporary `Test1` object, and passes it to the *copy-constructor* for the initialization of `objTest1` (though most compilers should *elide* this copying). You can simplify it as plain `objTest1(50)`.